# Correct way of implementing a Python class that calls external functions on attribute update

Tags: python, class, object

I am currently trying to implement a python class that automatically synchronized with a NoSQL database with implicit buffering, quite to the image of the [SLQAlchemy](http://www.sqlalchemy.org/).

In order to do this, I need to track attribute updates issued by the user and, on each attribute update, call functions that keep that object in synchronization with the database or buffer.

What is the best way of doing this in Python? If it passes through `__setattr__` and `__delattr__`, how do I do it correctly, to avoid messing up with garbage collector?

Comment: Do you only need to track updates to existing properties, or do you need to support addition and deletion as well?

Comment: @Thayne: right now I only need to track existing properties, no deletion or addition is expected and should throw an error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way to do it (the way I would recommend) is to use [descriptors](http://docs.python.org/2/howto/descriptor.html).

First you make a class for your properties, something like:

```
class Property:
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        #initialize the property with any information it needs to do get and set
    def __get__(self,obj, type=None):
        #logic to get from database or cache

    def __set__(self,obj, value):
        #logic to set the value and sync with database if necessary.
```

And then in your class entity class you have something like this:

```
class Student:
    student_id = Property(...)
    name = Property(...)
    classes = Property(...)
```

Of course in practice you may have multiple Property types. My guess is that SQLAlchemy does something like this, where Column types are descriptors.

Comment: I will try this out. However I forsee the problem that I would need to define a family of properties with different names referring to different indexes, sometimes same names for the same objects referring to different properties. Right now I don't see any other way but to do this with metaprogramming. Thanks for the answer though!